# How to run code on column data every 9th row?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I've got things working the way I'd like. However, it appears to be running on all rows in column K for K13:K5000.

How can I make this code only run for every 9th row after K13?

```vb
Dim xRg As Range

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error Resume Next
    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("K13:K5000")) Is Nothing Then
        If IsDate(Target.Value) And Target.Value > 0 Then
            targetRow = Target.Row
            offsetRow = Target.Offset(9, 0).Row
            Call Mail_small_Text_Outlook(targetRow, offsetRow)
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Sub Mail_small_Text_Outlook(targetRow, offsetRow)
    Dim xOutApp As Object
    Dim xOutMail As Object
    Dim xMailBody As String
    Set xOutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set xOutMail = xOutApp.CreateItem(0)
    xMailBody = "Hello" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
              "This client is now Committed & Complete and ready for your attention" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
              "Renew As Is?" & vbNewLine & _
              "Adding Changing Groups?"
              
    On Error Resume Next
    With xOutMail
        .To = ""
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "Committed & Complete"
        .Body = xMailBody
        .Display   
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0
    Set xOutMail = Nothing
    Set xOutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Use a `For` loop, step 9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After `targetRow = Target.Row` run a check to see if it is a 9th row. This can be performed using the Mod function to get the remainder of targetRow divided by 9 (after subtracting 13 of course since you're starting from row 13). Something like

```
Dim bIsNinthRow as Boolean
Dim ModResult as Long
bIsNinthRow = False
ModResult = (targetRow - 13) Mod 9
If ModResult = 0 Then bIsNinthRow = True
If bIsNinthRow Then Call Mail_small_Text_Outlook(targetRow, offsetRow)
```